# Where is the IApplicationBuilder UseCookieAuthentication extension method?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dnx

I downloaded a private git project other developers have been working on for a few months. When building the project, I ran into a few issues:

- To restore packages initially, I needed to do `dnu restore` from the command line. Package restore from within Visual Studio 2015 seems to work fine after that.
- One project still had a few missing references in .cs files. I fixed it by adding packages to the respective `project.json` file.

Now I am left with only one error:
`IApplicationBuilder does not contain a definition for 'UseCookieAuthentication`...

The code expects an anonymous function:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.AuthenticationScheme = "NLCookieMiddleware";
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/api/Account/Login/");
    //options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/");
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
});
```

What's confusing to me is that other developers builds are fine without having added any other references to their project.json files. The working file for them is:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "AutoMapper": "3.3.1",
    "Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "Data.EF": "1.0.0-*",
    "FluentMigrator": "1.6.0",
    "HtmlAgilityPack": "1.4.9",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "5.0.0",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0",
    "RazorEngine": "4.2.3-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Razor": "4.0.0-rc1-final",
    "premailer.net": "1.4.2",
    "Microsoft.Net.Http.Client": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Moq": "4.2.1510.2205",
    "Serilog.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final-10071",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.Net.Http.Server": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "StructureMap.Dnx": "0.4.0-alpha4"
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "CMS.Services.Contracts": "1.0.0-*",
        "CSharpSDK": "1.0.0-*",
        "Lookups.Contracts": "1.0.0-*",
        "Services.Internal.Contracts": "1.0.0-*"
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

I've added countless other packages and tried older versions of them with no luck:

- Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.Interop

Where does this extension method live? Why would other developers not have this issue?

Comment: For me just closing Visual Studio and re-opening it fixed this error.
I had added the nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies

Comment: This extension method is obsolete for newer versions of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies NuGet. If you're using modern ASP.NET Core, look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for. Note this comes with a gamut of other required upgrades/new libraries.  Sorry, it can be quite frustrating.  I share your pain. :)

Add `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0"` to your `dependencies` in your `project.json` file.